# Facebook like count accuracy issue. Showing zero even if it's not

Tags: wordpress, facebook, facebook-like

I have a wordpress website where I integrated the facebook like button on each article. It was showing correct like counts for a while now but suddenly it began showing zero number of likes.

[image]

Upon further testing, it is showing the correct number of likes only once I, the user, has clicked the Like button itself. (and refreshing afterwards)

[image]

What could be the cause of this issue? Is this an issue with Facebook's API? or has something to do with URL? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Just an explanation will help. Is there anything I'm missing in the question? A piece of code maybe?

Comment: Try checking the URL of the page as set in the Like button in the Open Graph debugger (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug). If there are any errors shown on the page, that could also prevent Likes from being recorded.

Comment: @subeeshb the thing is, it is being recorded properly the problem is the initial display of the count of likes. it is showing 0, but once you press the like button it will start to show the correct count.

Comment: Sounds like it could be a bug. You might want to submit a bug report at https://developers.facebook.com/bugs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue will happen only if you are using URL Masking for your website, which loads the page inside an iFrame on a different domain. see: http://ycouriel.blogspot.com/2009/11/hide-url-in-address-bar-using-iframe.html

The solution is to use Addon Domain instead of URL Masking (iframe).